# tips for my bank program not returning results

Tags: c

I am making a bank program with functions.1 called displaymenu that produces a menu d(make deposit),w(make withdraw),b(check balance) and
q(quit).2nd function is getdeposit which accepts balance as parameter and asks user for amount they want to deposit then add amount
to balance and return it to main function.3rd getwithdrawal same parameter (balance and subtract amount and return result)
last displaybalance it also accepts balance as parameter and displays currentbalance.then use a switch statement to select which function
to choose based on selection if they choose to quit respond thankyou. I am making my switch statements but am lost on what
to add my program is showing the menu but when i pick a choice it displays the letter i pick and sitting there instead
of asking me the options. Can someone please look over my code and point me in the right direction?

```
      #include <stdio.h>

    char displaymenu();
    float getdeposit(float amount,float balance);
    float  getwithdrawal(float amount,float balance);
    float displaybalance(float balance);


        int main()
        {

          char  choice;
          float deposit;
          float withdrawal;
          float balance;
          float amount;

          choice=displaymenu();
          deposit=getdeposit(amount,balance);
          withdrawal=getwithdrawal(amount,balance);
          balance=displaybalance(balance); 




           switch (choice)
          {

             case 'd':case 'D':
                printf("How much would you like to deposit?");
                break;

             case 'w':case 'W':
                printf("How much would you like to withdraw?");
                break;

             case 'b':case 'B':
                printf("Checking your account balance");
                break;

              case 'q':case 'Q':
                printf("Quit");
                break;

                default:
                printf("Invalid Choice");
          }

         return 0;
       }

         char displaymenu()
         {
            char choice;



            printf("Welcome to Federal Credit Union!\n");
            printf("Please select from the following menu\n");
            printf("d. Make a deposit\n");
            printf("w. Make a withdrawal\n");
            printf("b. check balance\n");
            printf("q. Quit\n");
            scanf ("%c",&choice);
            return choice;


              }


             float getdeposit(float amount,float balance)
            {

                float deposit;
                deposit=amount+balance;
                scanf ("%f",&deposit);
                return deposit; 

            }

             float  getwithdrawal(float amount,float balance)
            {

                float withdrawal;   
                withdrawal=amount-balance;
                scanf ("%f",&withdrawal);
                return withdrawal;  
            }

             float displaybalance(float balance)
            {

                printf("Your balance is %.2f\n",&balance);

            }
```

Comment: 1) Calling of each function is done inside `switch`. 2) `scanf ("%c",&choice);` --> `scanf (" %c", &choice);` 3) `printf("Your balance is %.2f\n",&balance);` --> `printf("Your balance is %.2f\n", balance);` 4) You need to update the current balance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes in your code now it runs perfectly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char displaymenu();
float getdeposit(float amount,float balance);
float  getwithdrawal(float amount,float balance);
float displaybalance(float balance);


    int main()
    {

      char  choice;
      float deposit;
      float withdrawal;
      float balance;
      float amount;

      choice=displaymenu();
                 switch (choice)
      {

         case 'd':case 'D':
            printf("How much would you like to deposit?\n");
            deposit=getdeposit(amount,balance);
            break;

         case 'w':case 'W':
            printf("How much would you like to withdraw?\n");
            withdrawal=getwithdrawal(amount,balance);
            break;

         case 'b':case 'B':
            printf("Checking your account balance\n");
            balance=displaybalance(balance);
            break;

          case 'q':case 'Q':
            printf("Quit\n");
            break;

            default:
            printf("Invalid Choice\n");
      }
     return 0;
   }

     char displaymenu()
     {
        char choice;



        printf("Welcome to Federal Credit Union!\n");
        printf("Please select from the following menu\n");
        printf("d. Make a deposit\n");
        printf("w. Make a withdrawal\n");
        printf("b. check balance\n");
        printf("q. Quit\n");
        scanf ("%c",&choice);
        return choice;


          }


         float getdeposit(float amount,float balance)
        {

            float deposit;
            deposit=amount+balance;
            scanf ("%f",&deposit);
            return deposit;

        }

         float  getwithdrawal(float amount,float balance)
        {

            float withdrawal;
            withdrawal=amount-balance;
            scanf ("%f",&withdrawal);
            return withdrawal;
        }

         float displaybalance(float balance)
        {

            printf("Your balance is %.2f\n",&balance);

        }
```

Comment: thank you one more question i need to add a do while loop to ask if the user wants another transaction. Would I put it in my switch statement or by the choice printf display menu?